# Flash as3.0 how to set the video resolution quality to 144p,360p,480p,720p like youtube?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i am doing a project. I need to change the quality of video for different user so I want to set the different quality of video like youtube, and I am using **Flash cc and as3.0.**
When I want to set the size e.g. 480px360p I using the code like that:

```
**var vid:Video = new Video(360,480);**
```

this way just set the player size,not the video quality, also I want to use a fixed size video player to play video even the quality of video is changed.
so anybody can help me? thanks!!

Comment: One more thing I missed, I will use the swf into HTML to play the video.

Answer (score 0):

Except you are playnig youtube videos, you need to implement your own mechanism.

What youtube is doing is:

1. Create different version of files for each resolution 240p .. % to max video resolution
2. Play the appropriate file depending on the resolution selected.

I suggest you look at he following "youtube video" about how youtube works.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OqQk7kLuaK4